# Rails loop and rowspan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues with rowspan in a loop in my form using conditional statements. My first Rowspan 2 is outside the loop and works fine, but my second Rowspan 2 is inside the conditional, therefore it does not work as it should. Is there a method to resolve this?

**This is what I'm trying to achieve**

[image]

**Form**

```
<table>
  <th>Header 1</th>
  <th>Header 2</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Phase</th>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Rowspan 4</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 2</td>
    <% Identity.all.each do |identity| %>
      <%= form.fields_for :indicators, form.object.indicators.where(identity: identity).first_or_initialize do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :identity_id %>
        <% if ff.object.identity.number <= 1.4 %>
          <td><%= ff.object.identity.description %></td>
          <td><%= ff.collection_select :phase_id, Phase.all, :id, :name %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <% elsif ff.object.identity.number > 1.4 %>
          <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 2</td>
          <td><%= ff.object.identity.description %></td>
          <td><%= ff.collection_select :phase_id, Phase.all, :id, :name %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable, but I think it's not working for you based on how you're partitioning the data.

Specifically, it seems like you're closing trs in weird places, as well as you create one rowspan outside the loop.

A more robust solution would likely partition the data into rowspan=X blocks (maybe by using group_by, in_groups_of, chunk)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Phase</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="4">Rowspan 4</td>
     <% Identity.all.each_with_index do |identity, index| %>
       <% if index.positive? %>
         <tr> #emit a tr in every row but the first
       <% end %>

       <% if index.even? %>
         <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 2</td>
       <% end %>

       <%= form.fields_for :indicators, form.object.indicators.where(identity: identity).first_or_initialize do |ff| %>
         <%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
         <%= ff.hidden_field :identity_id %>
         <td><%= ff.object.identity.description %></td>
         <td><%= ff.collection_select :phase_id, Phase.all, :id, :name %></td>
         </tr>  #Close a tr in every row
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I haven't tested this personally, but I think something closer to this format would work.  It would also be useful to see the html output you're actually getting to debug.